# how to activate websocket over SSL (WSS) in apache2.4 and cPanel server?

Tags: websocket, phpwebsocket

I'm using websocket over 8090 port in my website and it works correctly,
but my website is using let's encrypt ssl and browsers doesn't accept ws:// and it returns error so i can not use my non-ssl websocket in my ssl website.

question is how can i activate wss:// in CentOS Linux 7 (Core) OS and Server version: Apache/2.4.54 (cPanel)?